# Lightswitch screen does not appear in Visual Studio

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

When I run the application in Visual Studio, some screens are not visible!

[Screens when App is started in VS 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbOIj.jpg)

The currently deployed version on the web server, shows all screens.

[Published Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFBcD.jpg)

I cant publish now, since not all screens are shown.

Comment: do you have permissions set up in your application?

Comment: yes i do, i am in the administrator role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im hoping its going to be an issue as simple as this, if you go to your Project Properties, and check that the "Granted for debug" options are ticked. basically if these aren't ticked, then it will compare all your screens against the "TestUser" rather than the Administrator you are logging in as on your live version.

when they are check you are effectively ignoring the permissions so you can see everything while programming it. Ticking these has no affect over your live project.

[image]

Hope this helps